# .htaccess redirect if URL contains 3 parts

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is there a htaccess rule that can rewrite URLS as following:

```
https://www.example.com/folder/123/title-text/ to https://www.example.com/folder/subfolder/
```

The digit part of the url 123 can have 1 to 3 digits. I found the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z])/ index.php?k=$1
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/ index.php?id=$1
```

But this seems to redirect only if the first part has digits. In my case the second part of the url has digits and third part "title-text" must exist because I have urls such as /folder2/123/ which I do not want to redirect.

Comment: Is `subfolder` always a static (constant) part in target?

Comment: Yes it is static url.

Comment: Is your .htaccess inside `folder/`?

Comment: No in the root with some other rewrite rules such as non www too www and http to https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule as your first rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(videos)/(\d+)/[\w-]+/?$ /$1/browse [L,NC,R=301,NE]

# remaining rules come here
```

Comment: It is not working for me I used as following:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^videos/(\d+)/[\w-]+/?$ /$1/browse [L,NC,R=301,NE]`

<br />
to redirect example.com/videos/654/new-video/ to example.com/videos/browse/

Comment: Thank you, it is working for urls which does not exist at all but not working with the CMS (PHPVibe) I am using.

It works if I try `example.com/something/123/text` but not if I try `example.com/videos/123/text` the CMS somehow overrides this rule.

Comment: Just make sure this rule is very first rule after `RewriteEngine` line.

Comment: It is in the first line but still does not work:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(videos)/(\d+)/[\w-]+/?$ /$1/browse [L,NC,R=301,NE]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: The URLs do contain /videos but I still get 404

Comment: Never mind I just retried it and it works. Thanks for your help